# JTabbedPane will not fill entire JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am adding a JTabbedPane to my JPanel and I can get it to stretch to the edges but the JTabbedPane is still leaving an ugly border around it. I thought the edges you just merge with the edges of the window. Does anyone know how to make it do that? Here is a picture of what I am seeing.

[image]

Here is my method that creates the layout:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6112493789711533870L;
    private final int FRAME_WIDTH = 720;
    private final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 405;

    private JPanel mainLayout;
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    public MainFrame(String t) {
        super(t);
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        add(createLayout());
    }

    public JPanel createLayout() {
        this.mainLayout = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JTabbedPane mainTabs = new JTabbedPane();
        mainTabs.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.LEFT);

        JComponent projectPanel = makeTextArea();
        mainTabs.addTab("Projects", projectPanel);

        JComponent tasksPanel = makeTextArea();
        mainTabs.addTab("Tasks", tasksPanel);

        JComponent optionsPanel = makeTextArea();
        mainTabs.addTab("Options", optionsPanel);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);

        mainLayout.add(mainTabs, c);
        return mainLayout;
    }

    private JScrollPane makeTextArea() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(true);

        JScrollPane scrollTextArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollTextArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        return scrollTextArea;
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really remove that border. It's part of the JTabbedPane UI. However, the problem I always have is the opposite: the Nimbus look and feel is, infuriatingly, the only one that does *not* have a border around tab pages. So, if you really want to avoid the border, you can use Nimbus by running this code once at application startup:

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
} catch (Throwable t) {
    throw new RuntimeException(t);
}
```

Otherwise, I would suggest adding an extra empty border around the components so the thin border doesn't look as ugly.

Edit: Instead of or in addition to the above, try removing the JScrollPane's border by adding this in `makeTextArea()`:

```
scrollTextArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

This is what I see now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/afr8n.png

Comment: for some reason I added this bit of code and the borders are still there

Comment: I added it in the `createLayout()` method

Comment: that second line removed a good bit of it which is great. For some reason the UIManager is not changing the way the window looks. I may be adding it in the wrong place.

Comment: @zachstarnes Call `setLookAndFeel` at the start of the application, before creating any windows. *Or*, call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);` for each frame if you want to update the look and feel after it's already created. It won't change the window titlebar/borders by the way, as that's part of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the used look and feel, try for example

```
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

to use the system look and feel. It still has the border, but it's getting better. If you want to get rid of the border at all, you need to change the look and feel of the component.

Comment: The borders are still there. Even after I added the line above. Do I have to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the JTabbedPane directly to your JFrame... why do you need that extra JPanel?

Comment: took away the jpanel and the borders are still there